# To retrieve component label (menubar) in Bean using primefaces

Tags: java, xhtml, primefaces

Here is the code which is in Process.xhtml . 
We have a "Process" menubar under which we have "Data Report" and "Charts" as subMenuBars
We need the label name "Process" in backing bean when we click on either DataReport or Charts .

```
<p:menubar>               
 <p:submenu label="Process" icon="ui-icon-home"
            style="font-size:10pt;">
            <p:menuitem value="Data Report" icon="ui-icon-contact"
                url="DataReport.xhtml" id="DataExport"/>
            <p:submenu label="Charts" icon="ui-icon-star">
                <p:menuitem value="Bar Graph" url="BarChart.xhtml" id="BarChart"/>      
            </p:submenu>
            </p:submenu> 
 </p:menubar>
```

Comment: It can be done by, on the backing bean retrieve the 'parent' component of the current component.

Comment: please Kindly let me know how to do it.i am new on this.